# server.mappath returning wrong path

Tags: asp.net, server.mappath

Sever.mappath is returning wrong path that is I think it is converting the initial part of the path to lowercase which is the problem;

```
 String path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/");
```

When I check for the path in my page by storing it in a textbox it returns:

```
c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OFR\OFR\UploadImages\
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OFR\OFR\UploadedImages
```

What can I do to get the proper path?

Comment: Is it a big deal really ?!

Comment: I am using it to upload files. I could add the file directly to database but I wanted to try it this way also. Since the path is wrong, it is throwing an exception.

Comment: Since the paths aren't case sensitive, I imagine your exception (you haven't shown us the code that produces it) is more likely to do with the trailing backslash or lack thereof.

Comment: upload files using .SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/")+filename) ?
I don't think the exception occur by case sensitivity, you can shown us your code to get a detailed help.

Comment: @Moshtaf sorry for wasting your time. It was really my typing mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just spell mistake. you have to write like this

```
String path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/");
```

which will give your expected path

> C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\OFR\OFR\UploadedImages

Instead of **UploadImages** use **UploadedImages**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I literally surfed the net for two hours to try and get the exact path. It worked!